# Why does valid virtual shebang break venv on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shebang, python-venv

I'm trying to write a python3 script that will work on Windows and Unix.

According to [the python documentation on shebangs on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines), I can use virtual shebangs:

> To allow shebang lines in Python scripts to be portable between Unix and Windows, this launcher supports a number of ‘virtual’ commands to specify which interpreter to use. The supported virtual commands are:
>
> /usr/bin/env python
>
> --SNIP--

Further, I can add a suffix:

> Any of the above virtual commands can be suffixed with an explicit version (either just the major version, or the major and minor version).

So, I believe the following should both be valid shebangs on Windows:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

and

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

However, when I use the second version, my `venv` gets ignored:

## The Environment and Source

```
PS D:\> py -m venv venv
PS D:\> .\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
(venv) PS D:\> py -V
Python 3.8.0
(venv) PS D:\> type .\f.py
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

## Test 1: As Expected, the `venv` packages are in scope

```
(venv) PS D:\> py .\f.py
D:\
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
D:\venv
D:\venv\lib\site-packages
```

## Change the file by adding `3` as a suffix to the shebang

```
(venv) PS D:\> type .\f.py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

## Test 2: `venv` no longer in scope

```
(venv) PS D:\> py .\f.py
D:\
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python38.zip
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\DLLs
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
C:\Users\btg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages
```

Why does changing the shebang in this way mean the `venv` is no longer in scope?

Comment: Virtual environments, as well as the standard installation of Python, do not contain a "python3.exe" executable, so a `PATH` search in the standard case would return nothing. On the other hand, all active virtual environments, even in Unix, always have a "python" command.  In the case of the "env" `PATH` search, if the name starts with "python", the launcher will only search for the name if it's exactly "python". If there's any "X[.Y][-32|-64]" suffix on the name, it searches registered installations instead.

Comment: In development, cross-platform test scripts that should use the active version of Python -- whatever that happens to be -- should execute "python". Nothing else is supported in the cross-platform case. OTOH, scripts that get installed in the active Python -- e.g. via pip with a standard installation and package configuration -- will explicitly reference the environment in their shebang (e.g. "#!D:\venv\Scripts\python.exe"), and on Windows the script may be embedded in a mini-launcher executable (e.g. "f.exe"). Such scripts work whether the virtual environment is active or not.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough comments @ErykSun - if you rewrite as an answer I'd be happy to accept. To me, this seems like an unhelpful design decision: My understanding is that it is still commonplace for python 3.x binaries on UNIX-like to be called `python3` (as opposed to `python`), therefore it is impossible to have a cross-platform shebang for python3 using the default configuration for `venv` on Windows and the commonplace `python3` on UNIX-like..? I would've expected the Windows `py` launcher to be able to reconcile the shebang suffix with the version in use in the `venv`.

Comment: You're not alone. There are open issues about the lack of "python3" support for the launcher's emulation of Unix "/usr/bin/env". It's just no one has moved forward with a solution. The simple approach would be to stop searching registered Pythons -- or at least delay searching the registry in all "python" cases until after searching `PATH`. Let users resolve the "python3" problem on their own by manually copying or symlinking the executable.